# when i try to install SwiftAddressBook through pod install command, getting error as Error installing SwiftAddressBook

Tags: swift

When i try to install SwiftAddressBook pod to our project, am getting error as [!] Error installing SwiftAddressBook [!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/SocialbitGmbH/SwiftAddressBook.git /var/folders/gm/yb84x_bj7ss7bp4vx905jjq00000gn/T/d20181015-7032-1ovkm2w --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 0.7.1  Cloning into '/var/folders/gm/yb84x_bj7ss7bp4vx905jjq00000gn/T/d20181015-7032-1ovkm2w'...

My Xcode version is 9.2
swift version 3

Answer (score 0):

There is no git repository at https://github.com/SocialbitGmbH/SwiftAddressBook.git

Comment: That should probably be a comment